# Using xuggle without installing for a java web application

Tags: java, applet, screen-capture, xuggle, xuggler

I have created a Screencast applet for WIndows OS. The applet uses xuggle to encode and decode videos. It gives the following error when xuggle is not installed on the system as it tries to load some native code:

```
2012-07-29 12:40:28,452 [AWT-EventQueue-2] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - 
  Could not          load library: xuggle-ferry; version: 3; 
  Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-ferry in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:14)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:871)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
```

How can the installation be eliminated. So that the applet runs directly on any system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a newer Xuggler version. Starting from 5.4 it does not require installation anymore, native libraries are loaded from the jar file itself.

Comment: ya i tried its working :) There are OS specific JAR files so need not use JAR files containing all Native libraries. Rather check OS and JVM version and load particular jar file. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ & [Can I use Xuggler with Java Webstart or as an Applet?](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_use_Xuggler_with_Java_Webstart_or_as_an_Applet.3F)

> No, not today. We're interested in approaches to solving this problem, and if you have experience with making native libraries work in webstart (especially ones that have runtime dependencies you can't know in advance) we'd like to hear from you.

So, not only can Xuggler not be used in an applet *without* Xuggler installed, it also cannot be used in an applet on a machine *with* Xuggler installed.

---

*Please see the [jabal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864680/418556) that suggests the above is **outdated** information.*

Comment: The applet runs fine on my system when xuggle is installed.The moment i uninstall, it gives the Unsatisfied Link error.

Comment: Starting with Xuggler 5.4 no installation is necessary

Comment: @jabal That is good to hear.  You might want to enter it as an answer to the OP's [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11842799/418556).  The FAQ should be updated. -- It would be very hand if Xuggler was offered as a JWS extension.  There are several projects in which I would like to use it.