# Alternative of xuggler for video encoding which doesnot require installaion?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, screen-capture, xuggle

I am creating a screencast Java Web Start application.

Encoding Video using xuggler requires:

1. **installing xuggler on the client system** - Which is tedious.

(OR)

1. **Using xuggle-xuggler.jar version 5.2 or above whose size is around 35 MB plus.** - this increases the time required for the application to load.

**Is there any other alternative in which installation is not required as well jars are not so huge.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Xuggler for video encoding/decoding, only audio. However, I remember also seeing a warning that "Xuggler must be installed" etc etc. I found out this wasn't the case. You can quite easily copy the JARs and native libraries into your app and set them up in your classpath/library path so Xuggler works just fine without installation.

That said, I was using a 'standard' installer. Using Java Web Start may be different because the sandboxing is stricter. For example, loading native libraries.

The size of the package is something that's difficult to get away from... host on a CDN?

Comment: Re. JWS/natives.  Either an applet or JWS app. would need to be digitally signed & trusted to use natives.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11864680/418556).